# Append multiple file with cmd

Tags: cmd.exe, append

I have multiple file such as ox.001,ox.002,...,ox.0050.
I Want to append myFiles for example ox.001 to ox.0050 or ox.0060 to ox.0080 into one file then fileName result ox.0051 or ox.0081.

Comment: `COPY firstfile.ext+secondfile.ext result.ext`. If files are not text files - add `/B` key. You may use wildcards in source files list. No spaces before/after plus signs! If  `result.ext` is omitted, `secondfile.ext` will be append to `firstfile.ext`. In that case `firstfile.ext` cannot contain wildcards and cannot match any wildcard in `secondfile.ext`. See `COPY /?`.

Comment: I want to combine files that user select first and end file name.i think use (for function) loop  and define 2 variable for user choice file name in this condtion.

Answer (score 0):

> that user select first and end file name.i think use (for function) loop and define 2 variable for user choice file name in this condtion.

```
@echo off
:get1
set /P file1=Insert first source file name:
if exist %file1% goto get2
echo %file1% not found!
goto get1
:get2
set /P file2=Insert second source file name:
if exist %file2% goto get3
echo %file2% not found!
goto get2
:get3
set /P file3=Insert target file name:
if not exist %file3% goto docopy
echo %file3% already exists!
goto get3
:docopy
copy /b %file1%+%file2% %file3%
set file1=
set file2=
set file3=
echo Done
```

Filename may contain or not contain both drive and folder.

If some filename is LFN containig spaces or another special chars it must be enclosed with double-quotes while entering (correctness is not checked!).